# I can not install node-sass

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, npm-install, node-sass

After upgrading my Windows OS, I got an error while installing the node-sass package.

As shown in the output that I provided, the rest of the packages are installed successfully.

To fix this error, I added the path of python and node to environment variable names, installed visual build tools, tried different versions of Python, installed node in other folders and did all the methods that could be found in stack overflow, but I still get the errors.

Please help me solve this issue.

```
E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite>npm i node-sass
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'E:\\Programming\\ME\\Dibaji_Agency\\MainSite\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb download using dist-url https://npm.taobao.org/dist
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking Python explicitly set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "--python=" or "npm config get python" is "/path/to/executable/python"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "/path/to/executable/python" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "/path/to/executable/python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Parham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Parham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.9.12"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.12 found at "C:\Users\Parham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 18.12.1
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '18.12.1' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb download using dist-url https://npm.taobao.org/dist
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "18.12.1"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 18.12.1
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 18.12.1
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? Yes
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2022
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2022
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:420:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Programming\\ME\\Dibaji_Agency\\MainSite\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\Programming\ME\Dibaji_Agency\MainSite\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Parham\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-09T01_13_37_687Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1):

## Don't use `node-sass` anymore.

`node-sass` has been deprecated and you can easily fix this by installing the new version `sass`.

You can uninstall the old and install the new one

`npm uninstall node-sass`

`npm install sass`

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

1. **`npm cache clean -f`**
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `npm i`

Comment: I tried this method, but I still can't install node-sass and I get errors

Comment: Try Open command prompt/powershell/terminal, with admin privilege.  `sudo npm cache clean --force` , `sudo npm cache verify` , Delete the  `package-lock.json` file located ` `C:\Users\<username>`  and try install your project with `npm i`

Comment: It still didn't work and I got exactly the same errors as I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a common case of compatibility issue, with the mentioned windows upgrade you probably have installed the newest version of Node-js currently 18 but checking the https://github.com/sass/node-sass repo you can see that the latest supported version is node 17.

Just to be safer you can go even with Node 16 for now and install version ^6.0.

```bash
node -i node-sass@^6.0
```